# How to move ASP.NET MVC 5/SQL Server app from single server to multiple servers

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, scalability

I have a web application (ASP.NET C# MVC5 with SQL Server 2014 back end on a single server) that has become moderately successful. It is handling the load fine now, but I want to be prepared in the event usage explodes (as it may). The app takes a lot of data from the user in the form of images regularly captured from the user's webcam.

What would be the best way to begin moving from a single server to a setup that would be scalable? I'd ideally like to be able to simply add servers when we need to handle more traffic and processing (for facial/object recognition, etc).

I've done a little research, but haven't found anything I'd consider even a good starting point, so I'd appreciate even a point in the right direction.

Comment: What are you planning on expanding? The web farm or the SQL Servers?

Comment: That's kind of part of what I'm asking. I'm not sure even where to start or where I'd need to expand.

The images captured from the user are saved to the filesystem, with a reference in a SQL Server table. There are millions of rows in this table.

Comment: It's really going to depend on which resource you want to address first. First, however, I would get the SQL server and web server on separate VMs, set up a load balancer, and be ready to add more web servers to handle traffic. Additionally, you'll need a file server as well that all the web servers can read/write to to store your images. Hard to answer this question as general scalability is a very broad topic.

Comment: Hey Michael... that's the sort of info I was looking for... many thanks! If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider moving your files from filesystem to some CDN (Content Delivery Network) This will assure you high scalability. It can be for example: Amazon CloudFront or Google Cloud Platform

You can also consider moving your code (most resource consuming) to ESB (Enterprise Service Bus) for example MassTransit (free) or NServiceBus.